# External monitor connection works with HDMI but not VGA

Tags: windows-8, hdmi, vga, external-display, acer-aspire

I smashed my laptop screen so I have to use an external monitor. I can connect with an HDMI cord but not with VGA. I want VGA so I can listen to sound via headphones on the laptop, it's an Acer E1 series running Windows 8. Can anyone suggest a solution to get the VGA connection working?

Comment: Would knowing how to change the audio output to not use HDMI be of more help? I feel that in your scenario, you would be better off as HDMI would provide superior video quality? Without looking at the machine myself I am not sure I can help getting the VGA port working. All I will suggest is that the machine should have as one of its function keys a way to switch video output and that it should be able to detect whether a VGA or HDMI cable is plugged in. Make sure the HDMI cable is unplugged when trying to boot using the VGA output.

Answer (score 1):

Windows should automatically detect which output is connected and use that as its primary output when booted. If you are trying with both connected, disconnect the HDMI cable before turning on the PC and see if that helps.

If nothing comes out, look on your keyboard for a symbol that may represent a switch to an external display. Often this is <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. Try this sequence a few times waiting 10 seconds between each attempt (it may take a few seconds for the monitor to come out of standby).

These pictures should show you the kind of icon you need to look for on your Function Keys:

[image: HP Pavillion Monitor Key]
[image: HP Pavillion Monitor Key]
<sub>(source: [pctvcables.com](http://pctvcables.com/images/toshiba-monitor-key.jpg))</sub>

You can also try <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> however I feel that you would need to be logged in for this to work and more so an issue that on a laptop if you had both a VGA and HDMI plugged in, it wouldn't be able to determine which you wanted and would probably resort to using just the HDMI.

If the issue is deeper than just not having used the proper procedure to activate the VGA output then I am not sure what else you could try and it may be a hardware fault.

## Switching Audio Output

Not a direct answer to your question but more to your problem. To use HDMI with the inbuilt audio of the laptop, do the following once booted into Windows.

To switch the audio output from HDMI to either the internal speakers or headphone jack, use the following steps:

1. Open Control Panel by pointing to the upper-right corner of the screen, moving the mouse pointer down, and then clicking 'Search', entering 'Control Panel' in the search box, and then clicking 'Control Panel'. If using Windows 8.1 I believe that you can also right-click the start button and select 'Control Panel' from this list.
2. Select the Hardware and Sound category.
3. Click Manage audio devices, listed under the heading Sound. In the window that opens, a number of devices may be listed under Playback.
4. Among the listed devices, select the device described with 'Speakers' or 'Headphones' (respective to your needs),.
5. Click Set Default. A green tick mark should show that this device is now the selected output device.
6. Click OK to confirm and close the window.
   The audio should now play back via the selected output.

**Disclaimer:** I am not using Windows so excuse and correct any mistakes. Any additions or modifications have been made based on my recollection of the operating system.

**Sources:**

- [How to Activate/Deactivate Your PC's External Video Output Via the Monitor Key Method](http://pctvcables.com/monitor-key-method.html)
- [Configuring a PC to send audio via HDMI in Windows Vista and Windows 7](https://uk.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3416/~/configuring-a-pc-to-send-audio-via-hdmi-in-windows-vista-and-windows-7)
- [Where is Control Panel? - Windows Help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13764/windows-where-is-control-panel)

Comment: The second image link is dead.  Do you still have a source?